# Spring data JPA Many to Many performance issue

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities **Article** and **Connection**, there is many to many mapping that is represented by **ArticleConnection** entity.
We do persist **Article** and **Connection** separately and then use **ArticleConnection** to store M-M realtionship.

We are creating **ArticleConnection** entity objects by setting **Article** and **Connection** reference in it and using saveAll to store
all **ArticleConnection** entities in one go. In log I did see JPA fires one SELECT query to check if that **ArticleConnection** mapping already
exists and one Insert to persist that relationship.

This is causing perfomance issue , so lets say if there are 10 M-M records then JPA fires 10 select and 10 insert queries.
Finally we are able to fix INSERT by enabling batch , now JPA fires all INSERT in one go using batch but SELECT query still seems to be
perfomance issue.

```
1. Is there any way to bypass SELECT and INSERT those realtionship directly since we are sure those wont be exists already.
2. If not then is there any way to instruct JPA to do all SELECT in one  query instead of firing it one by one for each ArticleConnection record.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop spring data JPA from doing a SELECT before a save()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635827/how-do-i-stop-spring-data-jpa-from-doing-a-select-before-a-save)

Comment: No this not working in my case