# Spring Data JPA how to ignore select table before insert

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My Entity Class has id field and it using `@Id` and it's strategy is null. Default Strategy is `@GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO))`.

when I call the JPA save method, it always **invoke sql select before insert into** ,query log is like bellow:

**First Query**:

```
Hibernate: select dataeviden0_.id as id1_0_0_, dataeviden0_.block_hash as block_ha2_0_0_ from table1 dataeviden0_ where dataeviden0_.id=?
```

**Second Query**:

```
Hibernate: insert into table1 (block_hash, id) values (?, ?)
```

I could control the id myself, I want the jpa ignore select before insert ,how to do ?

Comment: Can you show how you are saving object?

Comment: I solve this by @Entity class  implements Persistable

Comment: and who knows what is `Persistable`?

Comment: JPA has no such "save" method. JPA has "persist" and "merge"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Hibernate Insert Without Select Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588657/force-hibernate-insert-without-select-statements)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `persist()` method rather than `save()`.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1011405

However, unlike save(), persist() does not guarantee that the identifier value will be set immediately on the persisted instance.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=951275

Taken from here [Force Hibernate Insert Without Select Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588657/force-hibernate-insert-without-select-statements)

Comment: But my Repository class extends JpaRepository<T, Long> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> , but JpaRepository and JpaSpecificationExecutor does not provide persist() ? while it provide save()

Answer (score 1):

The now no longer deleted answer by @Alien is basically correct. The statement comes from Spring Data JPA using `merge` and if you'd use `persist` it should go away.

For this, you'd have to expose the `persist` method in your repository. Which should be easy with a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and an injected `EntityManager`. If you only save new instances with that repository you can even provide the custom implementation for the existing `save` method if you want.

Comment: I undelete the answer so somebody may get benifitted..thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[bulk-inserting-existing-data-preventing-jpa-to-do-a-select-before-every-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054477/bulk-inserting-existing-data-preventing-jpa-to-do-a-select-before-every-insert) solve my question, the entity implement Persistable,and override isNew(){ return false; } , it will ignore select before insert, because

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
```

it the save method will judge entityInformation.isNew(entity) false, and reach my goal.