# Avoid Spring Data JPA Selections before Saving an Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is the scenario, I'm saving an entity(let's call it as CG entity) using Spring Data JPA `JpaRepository`. In this CG entity, we have so many entities  One-One, One-Many and M-M and inside these entities, there are more relations and so on. I'm setting CG entity by its primary key and add other entity objects to it. So basically this CG entity PK should use as FK to most of the other entities inside the CG.

Some of the entities are new and others are set by creating objects with given primary Id(so there is no need to use relevant repositories to find the object and set it). In model classes, all the primaries are set by manually (no Auto Generation Strategies) (I can't expose table structures as I'm not allowed to do it)
When I call the .save() function, JPA runs this function

```
    @Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

From here spring JPA checks whether CG is a new entity or not by creating select queries. When I use SQL query shown in the debugger I observed it uses nearly 70 SELECT queries. 
In spring documents [Persistable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites), I implemented it and set override `isNew()` to `false`. I did the same for those Objects where I created by PK.

But when I call `.save()` for the whole operation, spring data JPA runs nearly 800 `SELECT` queries before insertion and there are 70 `INSERT` queries(There is no problem with insert queries). It's taking around 20s to save an entry. I referred to so many threads related to this scenario and wasn't be able to find a good SPRING DATA JPA solution. (SO [Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373201/spring-data-jpa-how-to-ignore-select-table-before-insert) )
All I needed is to reduce the time of saving a CG entity. Is there any spring data JPA way to achieve this?

Comment: That isn't Spring Data JPA but just a JPA "issues". This is how JPA works and has nothing to do with calling save/merge. For existing entities it will do dirty checking to see if it needs to update things, it will also try to load references in those entities (the selects). What you want is to optimize this proces for batch processing and set flush mode to manual (instead of auto) and regularly flush and clear (in that order) the first level cache (the entitymanager).

Comment: @M.Deinum so you mean that I have to manually implement saving queries? can you share some tutorials regarding what you said? thanks for the reply

Comment: No I'm not. I'm saying you should optimize for batch processing and thus set flush mode to manual and call `flush` and `clear` at regular intervals. I'm nowhere stating you should write your own queries.

Comment: @M.Deinum ah thanks for your recommends, I will check about batch processing.

Comment: You need to update your question with the code where you construct and save the entity.

Comment: @AlanHay hi, as I said in Question, I'm using CGRepository.save()  to save the entity. I didn't add anything new

Comment: Yes, I know how Spring Data works. The pertinent code is where you **construct** the entity to be saved.

Comment: @AlanHay ah, here I used mapstruct for creating the final CG object and the rest. I cant provide the codes. I called the mapstruct functions I implemented and get the object of CG and pass it to the save function. hope you understand what I said :)

Comment: I don't think the high number of queries is because of this check. If you dig in, you can see the only thing it does is using the PK column you specified in the Repository<Class, ID> and check if it is null it be new entity. Anyway, if you are persisting many instances, try calling saveAll in batches.

Comment: It is hard to tell from the somewhat vague description but this might work better with Spring Data JDBC

Comment: @Brother it runs SELECT queries for every object in the CG entity and there are more queries.

Comment: @JensSchauder thanks I will chek that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was overcome by doing followings;

1. Setting `FetchType`

   It is needed to set all the `FetchType` to `FetchType.LAZY`.In my model, some of them were missing. There were no Fetchtypes were added. So to all `@OneToMany` relationship this was introduces
2. Enabling Transaction

   Previously in the Spring web app, transactions were not enabled. It was enabled by using `@EnableTransactionManagement` and relevant service methods were annotated as `@Transactional`

By doing above I was able to minimize the time spent to save an entry. Now there are nearly 200-300 queries running in 2-4seconds.

PS: always set FetchTypes for lazy